# What is the basis for subspace: $W=\{x \in R^4|x_3=x_1+x_2,x_4=x_1-x_2\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**What is the basis for subspace: $W=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^4|x_3=x_1+x_2,x_4=x_1-x_2\}$?**

I previously posted a similar question regarding showing whether this is a subspace but now I wish to find what the basis is.

I know if we have a linear combination of linearly independent vectors we can have the basis.

So since

$$X=<x_1,x_2,x_1+x_2,x_1-x_2>=x_1<1,0,1,1>+\ x_2<0,1,1,-1>,$$

would the basis be $\{<1,0,1,1>,<0,1,1,-1>\}$ with dimension of subspace $W$ being $2$? Or would it be $4$?

Comment: How many linearly independent vectors are in there?

Comment: the subspace has dimension $2$

Comment: Tip: use $\mathbb{R}$ (```\mathbb{R}```) to denote the real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is correct but incomplete. You should show that those two vectors, $\langle 1, 0, 1, 1 \rangle$ and $\langle 0, 1, 1, -1 \rangle$ are linearly independent, as you have only shown that they span $W$. This is not too hard, as they have zeroes in different positions.

Indeed, let $a\langle 1, 0, 1, 1 \rangle + b\langle 0, 1, 1, -1 \rangle = 0$. Then

$$0 = \langle a, 0, a, a \rangle + \langle 0, b, b, -b \rangle = \langle a, b, a + b, a - b \rangle,$$

so $a = b = 0$ and they are linearly independent, and so $\dim W = 2$. Also, I'd like to point out that saying **the** basis is bad usage. There will be many many bases for $W$. For example, scale up both vectors by $2$. It would be more proper to say **a** basis.